# Migrating to Angular 5 HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm migrating from this code (Angular 4 <) Http:

```
     this.http.post(url, dto, httpOptions);
       .map(this.extractData)
       .catch(this.handleError);
```

to this code (Angular 5) HttpClient:

```
this.httpClient.post<Hero>(this.URL, hero);
```

I've read this article: http://brianflove.com/2017/07/21/migrating-to-http-client/

My question is, I don't want to have to define the model on the client as it's already defined on the server. I don't want to have to always create the model in both spots. Why does it seem like people are ok with this? In the old way you didn't need to define the model (Hero). You simply got it from the server and converted it to JSON and went on you way... Is that possible now?

Comment: What about `this.httpClient.post<any>(this.URL, hero);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there's not a huge difference between `v4` and `v5`related to the `HTTP` module.

You can simply leave away the data model as you did before. This is how it looks like:

```
this.httpClient.post(this.URL, hero);
```

Or you could use `<any>` - depending on your coding style:

```
this.httpClient.post<any>(this.URL, hero);
```

In addition, you can make use of `RxJS` new `pipe` operator and refactor your code like this:

```
 this.httpClient.post(this.URL, hero);
   .pipe(
     map(this.extractData),
     catchError(this.handleError)
   );
```

To make the `errorHandler` work add this method provided by angular to your code:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
  return new ErrorObservable(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

Comment: well, I thought I tried the <any> but I guess I didn't. Works great. Thanks. Need to know more about .pipe()

Answer (score 0):

You can simply omit the type parameter or use `any`, it is not required:

```
this.httpClient.post(this.URL, hero);

// or

this.httpClient.post<any>(this.URL, hero);
```

From the docs:

> The HttpClient.get() method parsed the JSON server response into the anonymous Object type. It doesn't know what the shape of that object is.
>
> You **can** tell HttpClient the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.

https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response